How to retain previous cell value when drop down value changes in another sheet
I want to implement a formula in cell based on a drop down value in another sheet. However, if I change the drop down value, I want my cell to retain the previous value when the if statement was true. Can someone point me how to do that? For eg, drop down value is Abc, then apply formula in cell to calculate value. Let’s say cell value comes out to be 12. Now I change the drop down value to Xyz, the cell value should be retained at 12. I don’t want to use circular reference here and quite lost on how to implement it
I tried circular referencing to retain older value once if statement becomes true but looking for some better alternatives as this method may result in errors

Outside of Circular Referencing, this cannot be accomplished with formula.  It would take vba in a worksheet_change event.

can you step back and explain the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better way.
